# WCF Interop with WSE2.0

Tags: .net, wcf, interop

I'm attempting, with great difficulty, to have an WCF client communicate with a WSE 2.0. The wse service requires UserName token for authentication and it would appear that this is not possible over an unsecured channel.

I have configured the following custom bindings:

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="wse2Binding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressingAugust2004" />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
          </security>
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Digest"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://ecareweb/eCareMessaging1_1/Notification.asmx"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="wse2Binding"
        contract="NotificationSrv.NotificationSoap" name="NotificationSoap1" />
    </client>
```

Do you know of a work-around for this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: You _do_ know that WSE is obsolete, right? Especially 2.0?

Comment: I know. Unfortunately, the WSE services are hosted by a third-party.

Answer (score 2):

WCF does not allow you by default, but if you have exceptional circumstances you can still do it. 
[Here is some sample code for using ClearUserNameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html)

Answer (score 1):

WCF will not let you send username/password over an HTTP connection. If you have control over the service side I would suggest adding an HTTPS endpoint so you can use transport level security.

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but wondered if there was a work around for having to impose https.