# ASP.NET MVC 3 and WSE 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wse

I've an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and have been tasked with implementing a few UI controls. I need to call a few web services and bind the data to the UI controls. The problem is the web services host (we have no control over them) requires me to first implement a `UsernameToken` class (WSE 2.0) to authenticate the user and generate a security token. I understand WSE 2.0 is superceded by WCF in 2006. I don't want to switch back to VS 2005 to be able to use WSE 2.0. What are my options?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the approach Darin Dimitrov didn't work. What I have ultimately done is installed WSE 2.0, then added dll reference to `Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll` found in the WSE installtion directory (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WSE\v2.0\Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll). I also modified the Reference.cs file of the service to inherit from `Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol`. I was able to find the `UsernameToken` class and able to authenticate successfully.

I'm not an expert in this area so I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, but it worked nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Service Reference` to your ASP.NET MVC application and point it to the web service WSDL. This will generate a strongly typed WCF client which is compatible with WSE. Here's [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650778.aspx#wss_appx_interopcons_wse30_topic2) which covers the different interoperability scenarios

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've read the article you linked and am concerned with this - _"It is theoretically possible to develop Web services using WSE 2.0 in such a way that they can interoperate with WSE 3.0 (and WCF) by using only a reduced set of specifications specifically, SOAP 1.1, WSDL 1.0, and WS-Security 1.0. However, Microsoft does not support interoperability in this situation. The safest way to plan for interoperability with WCF is to upgrade the WSE 2.0 code to WSE 3.0._" And what if I have multiple WSDL's?

Comment: Like for example, I have `http://xxx/WSLogin.asmx` and `http://xxx/GetData.asmx`. Do I need to add _two_ WSDL service references one for `WSLogin` and `GetData`? I haven't done this before so apologize if this is a newbie question.

Comment: @user349308, in this case you could use the [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) command line tool to generate a strongly typed client proxy. It allows you to specify multiple service urls: `svcutil.exe http://xxxx/WSLogin.asmx http://xxx/GetData.asmx`. Obviously classes that are common between the 2 services will be created only once on the client.

Comment: Thanks. Just so I understand this correctly, I'll need to create a proxy class by using `svcutil.exe` and specify all the service urls I need. I should then add this proxy class (Add Service Reference?) to the project and I should be good to go. Right? And what are your thoughts about my comment earlier that MSFT does not support interoperability in this situation? Should I be considered? Thanks!

Comment: @user349308, you use svcutil.exe at the command prompt. It generates a .cs file containing all the client files. You no longer use Add Service Reference in Visual Studio. The two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks. I did all that and I got a cs file and a config file. I've copied the contents of the config file to my web.config. I've included the cs file in my project. Now, I'm trying to generate the token to authenticate myself at the host. I couldn't find the UsernameToken class. I know I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The sample code given by web services vendor is something like this - `Dim proxy As New webWSLogin.WSLoginWse
Dim LoginToken As UsernameToken
LoginToken = New UsernameToken(UserName, Password,
PasswordOption.SendHashed)
LoginToken.Id = "LOGIN"
proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(LoginToken)
proxy.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(New MessageSignature(LoginToken))
Dim loginUser As webLogin.WSUser
loginUser=proxy.Login(UserName)` I'm trying to replicate the same.

Comment: I just found a similar question on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425973/wcf-interop-with-wse2-0. Looks like what I'm trying to do is not possible.